# License Gradle Plugin - include output in apk

Tags: android, gradle

I am generating license information with [License Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin) but I have no idea how to specify output to be in any folder that will be in final APK.

This is my setup:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // Source for license-gradle-plugin
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // Plugin generates single html file with all dependencies' licences
        classpath "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.12.1"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"
```

Comment: How do you expect people to read the license if it is packaged inside the apk?

Comment: License Gradle Plugin generates XML, so it's possible to parse it with standard Java library

Comment: @PeterO, did you find out how to specify the output into the APK so we can display said licenses to the user at runtime?

Comment: @Sakiboy no, I haven't played with the plugin since that. I would try to generate files to the default folder and then copy them somewhere using gradle - this is just a tip, I haven't tried and have no idea if it will work.

Comment: Yeah I'll work on it and report back in the coming weeks.

Comment: @PeterO. The final `licenses.html` file is added to the application's `/assets/` dir, so you can access it from there at runtime. I am currently using this in my app and it is working fine.